# Web Scraper - PHP - Simple html dom

Tags: php, web-scraping

im scraping e-shop. I have list of urls, loading them and then scrape table. Well. First page is right it has maybe 30 parametres. And the next pages if have 20 parameters and dont have the parameter from the page before its copying them. And thats my question why? Maybe i just dont know how to clear the array, could u help me?

```html
//The code
foreach($odkazy as $odkaz) {
 
 //Here i am loading each page
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load_file($odkaz);
   
 //Finding code of prodcut
 $ptyp = $html->find("span.p-type");
 foreach($ptyp as $a)
 $item["p-type"] = trim($a->plaintext);



 //Here are values of product
 $hodnoticky = $html->find("dd");
 foreach($hodnoticky as $h) 
 $hodnota[] = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$h->plaintext);
 
 //Here are parameters
 $parametrici = $html->find("dt");
 foreach($parametrici as $p) 
 $parametr[] = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$p->plaintext);

 //Here i am mixing them.
 foreach($parametr as $i => $key) 
 $item[trim($key)] = $hodnota[$i];
 
     
 $items[] = $item;


 
 $html->clear();
 unset($html);

}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little more. I can't really understand the difference between page 1 and page 2.

Comment: Ok.. lets say u have on first page parametr power = 60W, ok? But on second page is not any power.. but its showing it is.. its copzing the parametrs from first page if they are missing

Comment: Ah, it's because you're never clearing the $items array between the pages in the for loop probably. I'll put a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the item array is never unset between loops. Try this:

```
foreach($odkazy as $odkaz) {

   // ... rest of your code here    
   $items[] = $item;
   $html->clear();
   unset($item); // ADD THIS HERE 
   unset($html);

}

print_r($items);
```

Comment: Well, that was the first thing i was thinking about, but stil same result.

Comment: The weirdest thing is the arrays are empty after unseting.. 
Could not it be a problem with assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. Thanks @JacobW. The problem was in another array.. I tried to unset $item.. but solution is to unset array with values and parametres. Thanks!

```html
 $items[] = $item;
 $html->clear();
 unset($parametr);
 unset($hodnota);
 unset($item); 
 unset($html);
```

Comment: Ah sounds good. Another alternative to unsetting at the end of the file is to define each of the variables at the top of the file. By defining at the top you still garbage collect and the code looks nicer.